# Plotly R Heatmap with Multiple Y-Axes

Tags: r, heatmap, plotly

So, I'm trying to overlay a couple curves on top of a heatmap in Plotly. I can do this if the new curve doesn't have a different y-axis, but when I try to add a second y-axis the heatmap disappears. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've played around with the order of adding the traces and various control parameters and nothing works. Below is the code I'm using, along with some pictures.

```
# Basic heatmap, pic1            
p <- plot_ly() %>% add_heatmap(x=time, y=freq, z=log(spec, base=10))

# Adding first trace, pic2
for (i in cp3c279){
  p <- add_trace(p, y=c(0,0.5), x=i, name='Change Point',type='scatter', mode='lines', line=list(color='red', width=1), showlegend=FALSE)
}

# Add new curve, pic3
add_trace(p, x=time, y=flux, type='scatter', mode='lines', showlegend=FALSE, yaxis='y2')
# Format axes, pic4
p <- layout(p, xaxis=list(title='Time', showgrid=FALSE), yaxis=list(title='Frequency', type='log'), yaxis2=list(title='Flux', side='right', showgrid=FALSE)
```

I can't get the images to embed right in this post, so here are the links:

pic1: [image]

pic2: [image]

pic3: [image]

pic4: [image]